# How to close all tmux windows when one window is detached?

Tags: bash, tmux

I have the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'ls' C-m \; \
  split-window -h \; \
  send-keys 'ls' C-m \;
```

when I run this script, I get two windows. When I want to close everything, I have to press `Ctrl+D` twice, one time for the pane on the right and another for the pane on the left.

How can I ensure that if `Ctrl+D` is pressed, both windows are closed automatically?

I looked into `trap()` but I'm not sure on how I can trap the `Ctrl+D` from within the window

Answer (score 0):

Sending trap to the split window seems to work:

```bash
function close_tmux
{
    tmux kill-server &> /dev/null
}
trap close_tmux EXIT

tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'ls' C-m \; \
  split-window -h \; \
  send-keys 'ls; function close_tmux { tmux kill-server ; }; trap close_tmux EXIT' C-m \; \
```